# Is there a way to ignore magic __set() of a mocked class with PHPUnit 6?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Say I've got a class `Foo` with a magic `__set()` method that prevents any non-existent properties from being set on the instance:

```
class Foo {
  public function __set($name, $value) {

  }
}
```

If I were to mock it and try to set a property that it doesn't have, if wouldn't work, for obvious reasons:

```
$foo_mock = $this->createMock(Foo::class);
$foo_mock->bar = 'baz';
var_dump($foo_mock->bar); // NULL
```

Is there a way to ignore or override the magic `__set()` method so that I would be able to set a property that wasn't defined in the class?

I know this is a pretty weird use case, but I've got a particularly untestable piece of code, and I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: You mean you need to set a non-existent property on $foo_mock?

Comment: Not allowing to set a non-existent property is a designed behavior of class `Foo`, I think forcing the mocked object to act differently makes your test invalid and should be avoided.

Comment: @Nima You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I'll look for a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Replace with Test-Double

If you just want a test-double where you can set arbitrary properties, you can get away with a `stdClass`. This depends on the typehint you have in place to expect a `Foo`.

```
$mock = new \stdClass;
$mock->foo = "bar";

var_dump($mock);
```

Example in online repl:
https://repl.it/KBqG/0

### Subclass To Test

If `Foo` is typehinted, what you can do is to create the mock by subclassing `Foo` and overriding the malicious magic method.

```
class Foo {
  public function __set($name, $value) {
    var_dump(sprintf("__set %s %s", $name, $value));
    die();
  }
}

class MockFoo extends Foo {
  public $set = array();

  public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->set[$name] = $value;
  }
}

function methodUnderTest(Foo $foo) {
  $foo->something = "mhm";
}

methodUnderTest(new MockFoo());
```

Example in repl: https://repl.it/KDSq/0

Comment: In my case all the arguments are indeed typehinted, so `stdClass` is not going to work.

Comment: Maybe if you showed us more about the actual test you want to write, or the method under test, we could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you force the mocked object to act differently from what the original class is designed to do, then can we say you're actually testing the original class?

You can do something like extending the `Foo` class and override the `__set()` method like this:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value
    }
}
```

And use this class in your tests instead of `Foo`, but then you can't claim you're testing `Foo` because you're testing `Bar` no matter if they are only different in one method, they are not​ identical.